# imwrite 16 bit png depth image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, kinect

I have the following code. I am trying to save a 16 bit depth image which I retrieve from Kinect v1 as a png file. I wrote the following code sample:

```
def display_depth(dev, data, timestamp):
    global keep_runningp    
    cv2.imshow('Depth', frame_convert2.pretty_depth_cv(data))
    depthf.write(repr(timestamp)+" Depth/"+repr(timestamp)+".png\n")
    namef="Sample_dataset/Depth/"+repr(timestamp)+".png"    
    cv2.imwrite(namef,frame_convert2.pretty_depth(data))    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:          
        keep_running = False
```

It works when I add the following code, which converts data from a 16 bit unsigned to an 8 bit unsigned NumPy array:

```
depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)
```

Without this line, I am just getting the whole blank/white png image. But I need to have a 16 bit png file.

How I can save it as a 16 bit png file?

Comment: If I create, say, `a = np.random.randint(0, 65536, size=(48, 48, 3)).astype(np.uint16)` and then run `cv2.imwrite('foo.png', a)`, I get a 16 bit RGB file. If instead I use `a = np.random.randint(0, 65535, size=(48, 48)).astype(np.uint16)`, I get a 16 bit grayscale image.  In other words, `cv2.imwrite()` works for me.  I think we need a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you.

Comment: you are saving `frame_convert2.pretty_depth(data)` this means you are NOT saving a 16 bit image but a 8 bit image. If you take a look to the [function implementation](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/frame_convert2.py) it actually does `depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: I implemented my custom frame_convert and was importing that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though type of my data was like this

> `<type 'numpy.uint16'>`

Solution , to my problem was adding this line to  my code

```
depth.astype(np.uint16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, was pulling my hair out over this.